# Is it possible to create an extension that appears in the Music app's sharing menu?

Tags: itunes, music, sharing, plugins

macOS of course has an Extensions control panel in the System Preferences,

[image: Extensions control panel in System Preferences]

so it is clearly possible to make sharing extensions that appear *somewhere*.  But not all of the sharing options that appear in Music are in the Extensions control panel:

[image: Music sharing options]

and those that do are very generic, so it's not clear to me whether I can extend the sharing options in Music or not.  Additionally, most of the extensions in the "Share Menu" category are *not* appearing in Music.app's "Sharing" menu.

Is it possible to write an extension that will appear in the Sharing menu in the Apple Music app?